# in table data wrangling, sqlite, subquery on the group count

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to get from this,

#### Import

```
Ntype   |Color|Code
:-------|:----|:---
example1|Blue |xyz
example1|Red  |xyx
example2|Black|zyz
example3|Grey |zyz
```

to this,

#### Export

```
Name    |Option_Name|Option_Value|Code
:-------|:----------|:-----------|:---
example1|Default    |Default     |
example1|Color      |Blue        |xyz
example1|Color      |Red         |xyx
example2|Default    |Default     |zyz
example3|Default    |Default     |zyz
```

The part that I've been stuck on is, how can I do a subquery on the count of the name, with the result containing more rows than I started with? Handled depending on if the name is counted more than once.

Comment: Isn't there any ID column?

Comment: What happened to Black and Grey? Why aren't they in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it counts how many rows per Ntype. (I've added MIN(Code) just to avoid another join in the final result.)

```
SELECT   Ntype, 
         COUNT(*) AS cnt, 
         MIN(Code) AS Code
FROM     tbl
GROUP BY Ntype;
GO

Ntype    | cnt | Code
:------- | --: | :---
example1 |   2 | xyx 
example2 |   1 | zyz 
example3 |   1 | zyz
```

Then, IMHO you need the union of two queries. First one for 'Default' values. One row for each distinct Ntype, and another for the rows with count > 1.

```
WITH c1 AS 
(
    SELECT   Ntype, 
             COUNT(*) AS cnt, 
             MIN(Code) AS Code
    FROM     tbl
    GROUP BY Ntype
)
SELECT Ntype, 
       'Default' AS Option_Name, 
       'Default' AS Option_Value,
       CASE cnt WHEN 1 THEN Code ELSE '' END AS Code
FROM   c1
UNION ALL
SELECT   tbl.Ntype, 
         'Color' as Option_Name,
         tbl.Color as Option_Value,
         tbl.Code
FROM     c1
JOIN     tbl
ON       c1.Ntype = tbl.Ntype
WHERE    c1.cnt > 1
ORDER BY Ntype, Code;
GO
```

This is the final output:

> ```
> Ntype    | Option_Name | Option_Value | Code
> :------- | :---------- | :----------- | :---
> example1 | Default     | Default      |     
> example1 | Color       | Red          | xyx 
> example1 | Color       | Blue         | xyz 
> example2 | Default     | Default      | zyz 
> example3 | Default     | Default      | zyz
> ```

<kbd>*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=4bcdd603d967452d434f849f67d33f1d)*</kbd>

Comment: I really appreciate all your help, still trying to understand how it all works together.  I was able to make a working query from your work, but not 100% on why it works.
Is that "MINT" a typo?  Was it supposed to be "MIN"?   If so, what is it doing for us?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's MIN

Comment: @TechZilla let me know if this is useful for you. I've tried to explain in, look at second query. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=dae0025d90401f76df13583151a73b02

Comment: It is, Thank you for all your help, I finally got it.